# Angular-Material md-menu not working

Tags: html, angularjs, meteor, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I am trying to create a toobar with a couple menus like a lot of websites have. For some reason the menu is expanding below everything else on the page and the menu takes up the entire width. Please help! Also I am using meteor for this app.

```html
    <body layout="column">
      <md-content layout="column">
        <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="start center" layout-padding md-scroll-shrink flex="none">
          <md-button ng-href="/admin"><h1 class="md-title">HOME</h1></md-button>
          <md-menu-bar>
            <md-menu>
              <button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
                Menu
              </button>
              <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item>
                  <md-button>
                    item 1
                  </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                  <md-button>
                    item 2
                  </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                  <md-button>
                    item 3
                  </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </md-menu-bar>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div ui-view layout="row" flex></div>
      </md-content>
    </body>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/akPEpK?editors=1010#0

Comment: @camden_kid yah that seems to be working great. Do you think my issue might have something to do with using meteor?

Comment: Disable loading of the meteor CSS file(s) and see what happens.

Comment: @camden_kid I'm not sure how to do that? Where do I find those. I don't see them in the index.html are they loaded through the meteor packages?

Comment: I don't know anything about meteor but just reading the docs - https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#css - it doesn't seem to be bundled with any CSS and you have to supply your own styling. Maybe the CSS of another part of your project is the problem. The only thing I can suggest is that you look at the menu bar element in the console and see if some CSS is affecting it.

Comment: I disabled all my custom css, there must be something being added that is causing problems. I think it might have something to do with this element being added at the bottom of the page, it contains the menu-content `<div class="_md _md-open-menu-container md-whiteframe-z2 _md-active _md-clickable" id="menu_container_0" aria-hidden="false" style="top: 60px; left: 8px; transform-origin: left top 0px;"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was using the angular-material package from NPM instead of from atmosphere. For some reason that made a difference

Comment: I had the same problem, except I switched from the google hosted cdn to a cloudfare hosted one and it fixed it. Weird.